# Override Qt installer framework Next button click action

Tags: javascript, qt, installation

I am trying Qt framework installer (dynamic page example). I added
QLineEdit  to get user input in the predefined page "ReadyForInstallation" which looks like:

[image]

What I want to do now is disable next button until the user enters the right key. But I couldn't find any documentation related to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Keep the **Next** push button as disabled by default either in constructor or in UI file.
QLineEdit emits signal which is `textChanged(const QString&)`. You can connect slot to this signal and in the slot you can check if the text entered is the same as the valid key. Here is the mock code which will help you.

widget.h

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QString>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class Widget; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Widget();

public slots:
    // Slot where you can for the validity of the key
    void onLineEditFilled(const QString&);


private:
    Ui::Widget *ui;
};
#endif // WIDGET_H
```

widget.cpp

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "./ui_widget.h"

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    // by default the next pushbutton is disabled.
    ui->nextPushButton->setEnabled(false);

    connect(ui->lineEdit, SIGNAL(textChanged(const QString&)), this, SLOT(onLineEditFilled(const QString&)));
    connect(ui->lineEdit_2, SIGNAL(textChanged(const QString&)), this, SLOT(onLineEditFilled(const QString&)));
    connect(ui->lineEdit_3, SIGNAL(textChanged(const QString&)), this, SLOT(onLineEditFilled(const QString&)));
    connect(ui->lineEdit_4, SIGNAL(textChanged(const QString&)), this, SLOT(onLineEditFilled(const QString&)));
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Widget::onLineEditFilled(const QString&)
{
    if(ui->lineEdit->text() == "0000" &&
            ui->lineEdit_2->text() == "0000" &&
            ui->lineEdit_3->text() == "0000" &&
            ui->lineEdit_4->text() == "0000")
    {
        ui->nextPushButton->setEnabled(true);
    }
    else
    {
        ui->nextPushButton->setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I didn't mention this in my question , Qt framework installer examples are written in Javascript (https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/qtinstallerframework-dynamicpage-packages-org-qtproject-ifw-example-dynamicpage-meta-installscript-js.html)

Comment: Okay. Could you please modify your question to mention this as well. I will check with the solution shortly.